# How return ajax results from fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've modified my collection overridding fetch method but the fetch return nothing.

```
var Friendscollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({


model:Person,
url:"https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User/",
idAttribute: "objectId",
parse: function(data) {

    return data.results;
},



initialize:function(){

   },

fetch: function(options) {
        var cur_user= Parse.User.current().id;           
          var res;  
     var ajax = $.ajax;        
   $.ajax({
//query rest che trova tutti gli amici dell'utente corrente        
type: 'GET',
async: false,
headers: {'X-Parse-Application-Id':'qS0KLM--h***PiTS3VMk','X-Parse- 
REST-API-Key':'nh3eoUo***Tks9--JIfIt1Gm'},
url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User/?where={%22$relatedTo%22:\n\
   {%22object%22:}",

success: function(data) {
    //  console.log(data );
      res=data;


    },
    error: function(data) {

      console.log("ko" );
    }


  });

      console.log(res); 
  return res;     





}


});



 return Friendscollection;



 });
```

if call the fetch, it returns empty collection:

```
 Friends.utenti = new Friendscollection();
 Friends.utenti.fetch({async:false});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: When you check your network log, does the site return expected data? Is it going to the right link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Backbone.Collection.fetch` method is not supposed to return the data but a deferred or promise object. The correct way of doing what you want is like this:

```
var Friendscollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person,
    url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User/",
    idAttribute: "objectId",
    parse: function(data) {

        return data.results;
    },

    fetch: function(options) {
        var cur_user = Parse.User.current().id;
        return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, {
            type: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'qS0KLM--h***PiTS3VMk',
                'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'nh3eoUo***Tks9--JIfIt1Gm'
            },
            url: this.url + "?where=..."
        });
    }
});
```

With that you can get the ajax result like this:

```
var friendscollection = new FriendsCollection();
var res;

friendscollection.fetch().done(function(data) {
    res = data;
}).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
    console.log(textStatus);
});
```

That code is asynchronous so you shouldn't expect `res` to be defined in that same block. That's what the callback for `done()` is for. To learn more about how deferred objects work take a look at [Deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)